# Правописание "не" с причастиями, имеющими зависимые слова

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия, частицы

Имеем предложение: *Выявлена установка не согласованных с заказчиком сплит-систем*.

Вопрос: пишем "не" слитно или раздельно?

Знаю правило, что с прилагательными "не" пишется слитно, если нет противопоставления и нельзя заменить синонимом без "не" — всё подходит, но мы имеем дело не с прилагательным, а с причастием.

Знаю правило, что с причастиями "не" пишется слитно при отсутствии зависимых слов и раздельно — при наличии зависимых слов.
Под зависимыми словами подразумеваются любые слова, зависящие по смыслу от данного, независимо от того, являлись бы они в соответствующем предложении актантами или сирконстантами.

В данном случае "с заказчиком" — зависимые слова от причастия. Следовательно, я считаю, что "не" нужно писать раздельно. Коллеги с этим не согласны.

Подскажите, кто что недопонял.

Comment: Вы так подробно описали мнение одной стороны, что хочется спросить, а зачем вам еще чье-то мнение. Чем "коллеги" мотивируют-то?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: Исправил "независимо" — надо было слитно (просто тоже пример с НЕ).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, ок. Нервничал и торопился, когда писал.

Comment: @behemothus, мотивируют тем, что "с заказчиком" — не зависимые слова, так как их можно опустить в этом контексте, а в таком случае и нужно будет писать слитно.

Comment: @KirillK Зависимые слова (а **они зависимые в любом случае!**) тут никак нельзя опустить: *Выявлена установка несогласованных сплит-систем*. Теряется смысл. Звучит так, что системы не согласованы между собой.

Comment: Ответ дополнен правилом и примерами Розенталя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, а коллеги — нет.

Раздельно пишется не с причастиями, **имеющими при себе зависимые слова**: *не разобранные хозяином вещи, не возвращенная другу книга, не напечатанная в срок статья*.
*Глубокая, **не тронутая даже шелестом** единственного сухого листа тишина простиралась в лугах.
**Не искушенные в борьбе и не изведавшие всех хитросплетений** вражеской тактики, они сразу оказались в плену соглашательских иллюзий.*
http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56

Вот что пишет Розенталь:
Если причастие употребляется в значении прилагательного, то и при наличии пояснительных слов частица не пишется с причастием слитно:
*Это всеобщее одушевление, блеск, шум — всё это, доселе невиданное и неслыханное мною, так поразило меня, что я в первые дни совсем растерялся.*

Сравнить:
*неподходящие для южных культур условия* (‘малопригодные’ — в значении прилагательного);
*написания, не подходящие под правило* (причастный оборот);

*по независящим от редакции обстоятельствам* (фразеологический оборот с прилагательным);
*рефлексы, не зависящие от воли человека* (причастный оборот);

*веками нетронутая земля* (в значении прилагательного);
*рябина, не тронутая осенними заморозками* (причастный оборот);

*ложь преступника так бесстыдна, порой так неприкрыта* (‘явна, очевидна’ — в значении прилагательного);
*дверь не прикрыта* (причастие);

*ученик неподготовлен* (прилагательное);
*доклад не подготовлен* (причастие).

У нас по смыслу на первый план выступает **действие, а не качество:** *установка не была согласована с заказчиком; не было факта согласования,* — поэтому лучше **отдельно**.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Знак относится к структуре предложения, а не к фразе, поэтому правильнее на него шрифт не распространять: запятая закрывает примеры, но не является частью примера; двоеточие тоже не является частью фразы.

Comment: И тем не менее в словарях обычно знак делают того же вида, что и предшествующий текст. У меня был вопрос на эту тему. Вот вопросительный знак я оставляю без выделения после цитаты, чтобы подчеркнуть, что не сама цитата вопросительная (когда он относится к вопросу автора). Но это особый случай.

Comment: Да, если шрифтом выделяется всё предшествующее. Но у меня только фраза и только примеры. Если уже очень-очень строго, то точку с запятой между примерами выделять шрифтом не нужно.

Comment: Надо! Должно быть на вид эстетично. Это важнее остальных принципов.

Comment: Не думаю, что ровная точка с запятой нарушит эстетику. Наоборот, чётче отделены примеры.

Comment: Что рассуждать? Загляните в словари. Только не ищите выгодных. ;)

Comment: Что-то такого не вижу, где выделяется только фраза в середине предложения, после которой идёт знак. Точка сокращения, естественно, примыкает к самому слову.

Comment: Ну вот: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0&all=x (обратите внимание на закрывающую скобку. И вот: http://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0476.htm после словарных слов.

Comment: Ну там вообще: первая скобка ровная, а вторая нет — абсурд. Словарь же кто-то перепечатывал и проставлял шрифты, ударения и цвета — опечатка. Оформление текста — это не совсем компетенция Грамоты. В другом не нашёл, да и определить шрифт запятой в таком качестве затруднительно.

Comment: У Аванесова точно жирная запятая после жирного словарного слова.

Comment: Ну вот здесь было бы тупо, если запятая была бы тонкой. Так лучше. Но это тот случай, когда весь текст (в данном случае одно слово) выделяется до знака (и знак к нему примыкает по оформлению). Да и вообще, оформление словарей — это отдельная наука (лексикография).

Comment: Всё, я сообразил, какой есть хороший пример, — Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105. :) Не только на этой, на любую страницу зайдите.

Comment: Но тут уже само собой разумеется. Розенталь объясняет пунктуацию. Будет сложно понять, если не выделить знаки после слов. Там даже больше смысл в подчёркивании знаков, чем самих слов.

Comment: Здесь, например, речь не о пунктуации: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105. И тут, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105, написано: "частицы *не,* одного или..." То есть только после курсивного НЕ запятая тоже курсивная.

Comment: Конкретно такую фразу не находит. Вы пересказали, а я ищу пять минут. Ну вроде нашёл похожее в конце. Это единый учебник, и подчёркивать в разных предложениях/параграфах по-разному ну никак нельзя.

Comment: Да, простите, не ту ссылку дал, повторил ту же случайно.(( http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php — эта. Ну вот, правильно, должно быть единообразие. Но выбрали они всё-таки **именно такой** стиль!

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны оба написания. Предпочтительно в бытовом стиле, пожалуй, раздельное - но только чтобы меньше вопросов было. Слитное написание по соображениям грамматики не исключается, более того, может диктоваться соображениями принятой в предметной сфере терминологии.

> Знаю правило, что с причастиями "не" пишется слитно при отсутствии зависимых слов и раздельно — при наличии зависимых слов.

Это не абсолютное правило, но в целом - рабочее. Сложности возникают по двум моментам. Во-первых, как верно заметили, при определении понятия зависимых слов.

> мотивируют тем, что "с заказчиком" — не зависимые слова, так как их можно опустить в этом контексте

Это никуда не годится. Вопрос, можно ли "опустить", вообще никак не связан с понятием "зависимое слово".

**Зависимое слово - это слово, к которому задается вопрос от главного слова. Например, в словосочетании "умный парень" слово "парень" - главное слово.** У вас: "не согласованные" (с кем?) с заказчиком. По-другому тут поставить вопрос невозможно. Так что слова "с заказчиком" в вашем примере однозначно и безусловно ***зависимые***.

Но это было во-первых. Сложнее обстоит дело со второй частью (*если нет противопоставления и нельзя заменить синонимом без "не"*). Что нет противопоставления, можно принять как данность, а "нельзя заменить" - это очень плохая, школьная формулировка. Суть этого положения в том, что рассматриваются случаи, когда слова со слитным "не" образуют понятия, отличающееся от простого отрицания понятия без "не". Правда, с причастиями это происходит крайне редко, а вот с прилагательными вполне возможно. Поэтому сложилось такое ошибочное мнение, что наличие зависимых слов позволяет считать слово причастием и поэтому только требуется раздельное написание. Все не так просто, у прилагательного вполне могут быть зависимые слова и прилагательное "несогласованный" вполне может существовать ("халтурщики-музыканты издавали звуки, несогласованные друг с другом" - очень сомнительно, что здесь причастие да еще с раздельным написанием).

> согласованный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. (обнаруживающий взаимное согласие, единство) -ан, -анна (их действия согласованны)

[БТС Лопатина](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

Итак, вопрос упирается в определение того, что есть "не()согласованный" в вашем контексте. Я соглашусь, что у вас скорее именно причастие и нового понятия с отрицанием скорее не образует. Но исключить полностью вариант слитного написания даже причастия (а вдруг там новое понятие?) я не могу. Тем более, если по контексту получится, что это именно прилагательное, есть же понятия "несогласованные строения" (и это их качество, а не состояние, к отрицанию согласованности не сводящееся), то есть прилагательное "несогласованный" тоже по контексту исключить нельзя. А в этом случае слитное написание будет предпочтительное.

Итак -

***Выявлена установка не согласованных с заказчиком сплит-систем*** - естественное написание.
***Выявлена установка несогласованных с заказчиком сплит-систем*** - представляется возможным, если "несогласованный" используется в значении близком к "незаконный", "самодеятельный".

*Уфф... Извините, если длинно и путано. Вопрос оказался неожиданно сложным для изложения, хотя суть проста. И эту суть своего понимания, надеюсь, я донес.*

Comment: Подставим: *незаконных с заказчиком; самодеятельных с заказчиком*. Ну даже примерно - нет, потому что на первый план выступает действие: *не согласовывали с заказчиком*, а не качество законности или самоуправства.

Comment: *если "несогласованный" используется в значении близком к "незаконный", "самодеятельный".* - где у меня слово "подставим"? И вообще, давайте уже нормальные комментарии по ответу, а не по своим тараканам.

Comment: Близкое значение можно подставить хотя бы примерно. А если нет - то и значения такого нет!

Comment: @oleedd *Близкое значение можно подставить хотя бы примерно* - я обю этом ничего не говорил. Я уже сказал, комментарии, к ответу не относящиеся, буду игнорировать.

Comment: Это я вам говорю. Это довольно очевидно.

Answer (score 1):

***Выявлена установка не согласованных с заказчиком сплит-систем.***

Какой смысл этого предложения, что произошло?  Установили не те сплит-системы? Или установили лишние сплит-системы, которых не было в плане?

В первом случае  это будут ***не согласованные (конструктивно) с заказчиком сплит-системы*** (согласуются сами системы). Тогда это причастие, раздельное написание НЕ

Во втором случае это будут ***несогласованные с заказчиком (НЕЗАКОННЫЕ) сплит-системы*** (согласуется их установка). И тогда  причастие по значению соответствует прилагательному (можно заменить прилагательным-синонимом), поэтому допускается слитное написание.

Comment: *Выявлена установка незаконных сплит-систем.* — нормально. *Выявлена установка незаконных с заказчиком сплит-систем.* — не подходит. Предлог "с" указывает на действие, а не на качество. Такое ощущение, что вы это слово ("незаконные") скопировали у behemothus'а.

Comment: Ну да, скопировала, как Вы догадались.  Своих слов и мыслей не хватает, вот и приходится  у других переписывать. А Вам такой совет: изучайте лучше грамматику, полезное, знаете ли,  дело. Причастия - это форма глагола, и зависимые слова переходят из глагольного сочетания к причастию, они-то и влияют на написание НЕ. А вот прилагательное может иметь собственные зависимые слова, поэтому это Вам не стоит  КОПИРОВАТЬ синтаксические конструкции, считая, что у причастия и у прилагательного они одинаковые.

Comment: Могу дать Вам такой совет: изучайте лучше грамматику, полезное, знаете ли, дело. Причастия - это форма глагола, и зависимые слова переходят из глагольного сочетания к причастию, они-то и влияют на написание НЕ. А вот прилагательное может иметь собственные зависимые слова, поэтому это Вам не стоит КОПИРОВАТЬ синтаксические конструкции, считая, что у причастия и у прилагательного всё одинаковое.  Здесь можно всё сочетание заменить синонимом: несогласованные с заказчиком - отсутствующие в документации

Comment: Я считаю, что заменять нужно исключительно причастия (без зависимых слов). "Изучайте лучше грамматику" — так я изучил данный параграф Розенталя. В его примерах отлично видна разница. Но она не прослеживается в примере из вопроса. Ну нет здесь качества, в отличие от примеров Розенталя.

Comment: Вы еще обратите внимание, как оппоненты автора мотивируют свое мнение: "мотивируют тем, что "с заказчиком" — не зависимые слова, так как их можно ОПУСТИТЬ в этом контексте". Несогласованные с заказчиком - это значит незапланированные,  а это уже качественное значение. Вообще же говоря, все эти грамматические тонкости того не стоят, чтобы уделять им так много внимания. Это орфографическое правило достаточно условно и обычно применяется чисто формально (то есть используется раздельное написание отглагольных форм при наличии зависимых слов), так как мало кто может объяснить его смысл.

Comment: На тот комментарий сразу и ответил, что при опускании теряется смысл: *Выявлена установка не согласованных сплит-систем.* — явно звучит, что системы несогласованы (прослеживается качество и можно написать отдельно) между собой. Да и опускание не влияет на факт зависимости слов. Мы заменяем только деепричастие синонимом (без зависимых слов) — иначе мухлёж. Похоже, что вы слишком прониклись ответом behemothus'а. "Правило достаточно условно" — согласен, но логика примеров Розенталя прослеживается чётко.

Comment: Ладно, закончим разговор, он не имеет смысла, так как Вы опять переходите на лирику (высказываете утверждения, непонятно чем обоснованные), а это не мой метод. И имейте в виду, что я никогда и ничьим мнением "не проникаюсь",  мне вполне достаточно своего.

Comment: Вот вам конкретика. Сами зависимые слова сильно влияют на написание. *Каковы эти звуки? — какие-то несогласованные [между с собой].* Они несогласованные сами по себе и без зависимых слов. | *Каковы эти системы? — Какие-то не согласованные с заказчиком.* Не подходит — вот такими способами оно и проверяется. Они не в данный момент таковы, а не **были** согласованы. Здесь отсутствует качество, но в первом примере оно явно присутствует.

Comment: "высказываете утверждения, непонятно чем обоснованные" — Всегда указывайте на утверждения, с которыми не согласны. Я так всегда делаю. Иначе сложно разобраться.

Comment: Хотите продемонстрировать безупречную логику мышления  в этой теме?  Тогда попробуйте ответить на мой вопрос, заданный на форуме. Только коротко, убедительно и желательно без лирики.